# How to open a .sql file in SQLite Expert Personal?

Tags: sqlite

I have a .sql file that contains a database and i'm trying to open it with SQLite but i can't execute any of the command in the file as the below screenshot, any help with this?

[SQLite snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWkHM.png)

Comment: The .sql file creates a MySql database. It has nothing to do with SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

From a sqlite prompt:

```
sqlite> .read Sc4x_GA_screwy_db.sql
```

Or:

```
cat Sc4x_GA_screwy_db.sql | sqlite3 database.db
```